Meaning of the word "flustration"
One of the customers who uses our software product, in which I am in L3 support, I have seen they've used the word flustration. It cannot be frustration instead, because in oral language our higher team L2 may say that the customer is frustrating.
But the customer doesn't use this kind of word frustration in our case management system.
What might be the meaning of this kind of word - flustration?

In addition to the reasonable answer below, it's possible that they are creating a portmanteau using the words "flustered" and "frustrated".  Why they would do so is impossible to say.

This is a very obscure (obsolete according to the dictionary) noun meaning the state of being flustered. It's more likely to be a typo for frustration. Context would be helpful. Where is the customer from? are they native speakers? Either way I would avoid using this word yourself.

I am not sure which region that customer belongs to. They may not be native English speakers. However they must be originated from either Europe or U.S. mostly.

The word is reasonably obvious in it's meaning but no native speaker would use it unless being deliberately obtuse. I can't speak for AmE speakers but I'd be amazed if the answer was different there.

Various speakers of different languages have problems with distinguishing English "l" and "r" (particularly alveolar approximant or flap/tap) if there's no equivalent phonemic distinction in their language, so it's possible they were confused. Or they could have started typing one thing and finished typing another word entirely.
